# Parallel execution of network call in rxjava 1 and 2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a network call in which 300 ids will be returned and I need to make a network call for each id and compined the result in list. I was trying to use flatmap to do this but getting issue.

is there any way to define the number of thread creation for paral
Can anyone give me a example for parallel execution of network call to get the result fast in android with rxjava1 and rxjava2.

this is the code from fragment to get all record:

```
private void subscribeToStories() {
    contentValues.clear();
    if (isOnline()) {
        //Provider provider = Inject.provider();
        subscription =
        new HNewsApi().getTopStories()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Post>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscription.unsubscribe();
                        }
 //                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
//                                @Override
//                                public void run() {
//                                                   
/ /                                }
//                            }).start();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(final Post total) {
                        contentValues.add(mapStory(total));
                        Inject.dataPersister().persistStories(contentValues);
                        //contentValues.add(mapStory(total));
                        //Log.e("Storytitle",""+total.getTitle());
                    }
                });
    } else {
        stopRefreshing();
    }
}
```

This is my call with rxjava:

```
    public Observable<Post> getTopStories() {
    return hackerNewsService.getTopStories().limit(20)
            .concatMap(new Func1<List<Long>, Observable<? extends Post>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends Post> call(List<Long> longs) {
                    return getPostsFromIds(longs);
                }
            });
}


public Observable<Post> getPostsFromIds(List<Long> storyIds) {
    return Observable.from(storyIds)
            .concatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Post>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Post> call(Long aLong) {
                    return     hackerNewsService.getStoryItem(String.valueOf(aLong));
                }
            });
}
```

I would like to do parallel execution and return a List of Post object instead of Post from here.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` has parameter called `maxConcurrency`, there you can define number of threads that flatMap can spawn. Default is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so I think that was the problem.